# RouterLink not working Header MegaMenu

Tags: angular, routerlink

I am currently working in ecommerce website in angular5. I am facing an issue in routerLink navigation. When i use routerLink in netsted ngFor the routerlink triggering at first time only..second clicks not working. But when i am click sublevel menu and click my main menu its working. Can u please any one help me out. I am facing this issue for past 2 days and not able to solve. Here is my code :

```
 <li *ngFor="let menu of menus">
      <a [routerLink]="['/shop',cn,ln,menu.menuId]" class="navtext">
        <span>{{menu.menuName}}</span>
      </a>
      <div class="wsshoptabing wtsbrandmenu clearfix">
        <div class="wsshoptabingwp clearfix">
          <ul class="wstabitem02 clearfix">

            <li *ngFor="let category of menu.categories; let menuCategory = index" [ngClass]="{'wsshoplink-active':menuCategory == (selectedRow?selectedRow:0)}"
              >
              <a 
              [routerLink]="['/shop',cn,ln,menu.menuId,category.categoryId]">{{category.categoryName}}</a>
              <div class="wsshoptab-active wstbrandbottom clearfix">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4" 
                      *ngFor="let subCategory of category.subCategory">
                        <ul class="wstliststy02 clearfix">
                          <li class="wstheading clearfix">
                            <a [routerLink]="['/shop',cn,ln,menu.menuId,category.categoryId,subCategory.id]">
                              {{subCategory.name}}
                              <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                            </a>
                          </li>
                          <li *ngFor="let subLevel of subCategory.subLevelCategory">
                            <a [routerLink]="['/shop',cn,ln,menu.menuId,category.categoryId,subCategory.id,subLevel.subLevelCategoryId]">
                              {{subLevel.subLevelCategoryName}}</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                      <img src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-be11ba5cb1572b4b0051e9930325cbd9" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
```